# Java pattern multiline matching on java file

Tags: java, regex, multiline

I need to extract the following pattern:

```
public void convert(String sourceName, String destName,
        ProgressListener progressListener, Decoder.Params decoderParams)
        throws JavaLayerException
```

or it can have the form of

```
public void convert(String sourceName, String destName)
```

or

```
public void convert(String sourceName, String destNam)
        throws JavaLayerException
```

I am using the following pattern but the pattern is only identifying 2nd prototype only not 1st and 3rd.
The pattern being used is :

```
Pattern exp = Pattern.compile("([^(\n\t]*)"+Pattern.quote(obracket)+"([^()\n\t]*)"+Pattern.quote(cbracket));
where obracket="(" and cbracket=")";
```

Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, you're using Java to read and parse a file written in Java? This seems like a rather large code smell. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: as Jack pointed out y are you trying to parse this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with `singleline` mode..

```
\\s+(public|private|protected)?\\s+\\w+\\s+[\w$]+\\([^()]*\\)\\s+(throws\\s+[\\w$]+)?
```

Comment: By `singleline`, you mean `DOTALL` mode?  Or are you saying *not* to set `MULTILINE` mode?  It doesn't matter anyway, since nothing in your regex is affected by either `DOTALL` or `MULTILINE` or mode.